# Ubuntu does not connect to the internet by cable, I already tried all the common solutions that I found. Could you help me?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, windows, internet, restart

I have Ubuntu and Windows installed on the same computer, but only when I first enter Windows and then Ubuntu, the Internet works in Ubuntu, then if I restart it and enter Ubuntu first, the Internet does not work.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: "*I already tried all the common solutions that I found*" suggests that you already did a bit of research. If true, then you already know most of the troubleshooting information that we need to help you...however none of it is in your question. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like windows is giving an address to your Nic (network card) which is retained when rebooted.  This probably means that you don't have DHCP set up correctly in Ubuntu.  There is a network setup tool in Ubuntu GUI, which you can access by default at the top right of the screen.  I'd suggest you have a look in there and make sure DHCP is set to on.  Also make sure that nothing is set to manual addresses.

As a bit of background information, the DHCP client is the ubuntu / windows system that broadcasts to the network to ask for an IP address, DNS server and gateway / router address. If it finds a DHCP server, the server will offer your ubuntu / windows systems the relevant IP addresses for communicating on the network, which typically the client will accept.  Unless you've done something fancy, the DHCP server will be on your home router.

So you can see, having a correctly configured DHCP client in Ubuntu is critical.  This would usually default to being on, so if it's changed, chances are you manually changed it.

Comment: It doesn't work either, I think that's the problem but the solutions I found don't work. The "ipconfig / release" does not work, nor does it work by updating the adapter driver, nor by disabling the WOL. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried using Netplan in the console?  I think that's what you're after.  Also BTW, linux uses ifconfig rather than ipconfig.  Easy to get confused when coming from windows.  We've all been there.

Comment: Not sure if I can add links here - but there are a few that step you through it if you search for how to set up DHCP client on Ubuntu. e.g.  https://linuxhint.com/configure-ubuntu-dhcp-client/